# Passing dynamically a default date for v-date-picker from parent component and returning the changed date from child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-props

I have a custom component using the `v-date-picker` which is used in a lot of places. I want to be able to dynamically set the "default" date picked from the parent component, while being able to modify the date from the child component.

Here's the code in the parent component:

```js
<template>
  <DatePickerMenu @selectedDate="selectedExpirationDate" :selectedDate="this.date"></DatePickerMenu>
</template>

<script>
data() {
    return {
      date: '2021-04-29', //used for testing, will eventually come from a certain calculation inside this parent component
    }
},
methods: {
selectedExpirationDate(value) {
      this.expiration_date = value;
    },
},
</script>
```

In the child component:

```
<template>
  <v-menu
    ref="datePickerMenu"
    v-model="datePickerMenu"
    :close-on-content-click="false"
    :return-value.sync="selectedDate"
    transition="scale-transition"
    offset-y
    min-width="auto"
  >
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
      <v-text-field
        class="form"
        v-model="selectedDate"
        label="Expiration date *"
        hint="Minimum expiration date: one week from today"
        prepend-icon="mdi-calendar"
        readonly
        v-bind="attrs"
        v-on="on"
        :rules="requiredRules"
      ></v-text-field>
    </template>
    <v-date-picker
      v-model="selectedDate"
      no-title
      scrollable
      color="primary"
    >
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-btn
        text
        color="primary"
        @click="datePickerMenu = false"
      >
        Cancel
      </v-btn>
      <v-btn
        text
        color="primary"
        @click="$refs.datePickerMenu.save(selectedDate)"
      >
        OK
      </v-btn>
    </v-date-picker>
  </v-menu>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "DatePickerMenu",
  data () {
    return {
      datePickerMenu: false,
      //selectedDate: this.setSelectedDate, and changing the 'selectedDate' props to setSelectedDate
    }
  },
  props: ['selectedDate'],
  watch: {
    selectedDate: function() {
      this.$emit('selectedDate', this.selectedDate);
    },
  },
}
```

When I do this, the date-picker shows the correct date passed from the parent component, but when I change the selected date, the following message appears:

```
[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "selectedDate"
```

So as you can see, I tried setting a local data with the passed props `//selectedDate: this.setSelectedDate,` but when I do so, the default selected date works the first time, but when it's changed in the parent component, it won't update in the child's.

Hopefully my problem is clearly explained.. Any solution ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.sync` modifier like so:

in your parent:

```js
<DatePickerMenu
    :selectedDate.sync="this.date"
    @selectedDate="selectedExpirationDate" 
/>
```

and in your child component, create a computed like so:

```html
<v-date-picker
    v-model="selectedDateComputed"
    no-title
    scrollable
    color="primary"
>
```

```js
computed: {
  selectedDateComputed: {
     get(): {
        return this.selectedDate;
     }
     set(newDate): {
        this.$emit('update:selectedDate', newDate);
     }
  }
}
```

of course you need to use this for `v-text-field` as well.

you can see the [vue sync modifier docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working like a charm, big thanks!

FYI, it was the perfect approach, but there were some syntax errors:

```
computed: {
    selectedDateComputed: {
     get: function () {
        return this.selectedDate;
     },
     set: function(newDate) {
        this.$emit('update:selectedDate', newDate);
     }  
  },
```

Comment: Glad i could help! But it is weird, my syntax should work - maybe you have problem with Babel configuration to support es6? I always prefer working with the new syntax it is much cleaner (not only with functions, but with everything)